# Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer (n) and print n lines of output

Tags: java, loops

Write a program that asks the user to enter an integer (n) and print n lines of output, with n characters on the first line, n-1 characters on the second line, …, and 1 character on the last line. Each line must start with the character ‘A’.  The number of characters on the first line will be n, with the characters being

```
A b C d E f G h I j K l M n O p Q r S t U v W x Y z
```

Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("How many rows for Pattern 2?: ");
        int p2 = input.nextInt();
        String s = input.nextLine();

        char ch;
        int i1 , j1;
        for(i1 = p2; i1 >= 1; i1--){
            ch = 'A';
            for(j1 = 1; j1 <= i1; j1++){
                System.out.print(" " + ch++);

            }
```

When I tried to run the program

I got This String:

```
How many rows for Pattern 2?: 
16
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M
 A B C D E F G H I J K L
 A B C D E F G H I J K
 A B C D E F G H I J
 A B C D E F G H I
 A B C D E F G H
 A B C D E F G
 A B C D E F
 A B C D E
 A B C D
 A B C
 A B
 A
```

How can I get output like this:

```
How many rows for Pattern 2?: 7

    A b C d E f G
    A b C d E f
    A b C d E
    A b C d
    A b C
    A b
    A
```

Comment: Looks like you need an inner if test to make even letters lower case.

Comment: Or you can just write the first n letters of String PrintStr = "A b C d E f ...";

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `j1` is divisible by 2, obtain the character from `j1` as `'a' + j1 - 1`.
If `j1` is not divisible by 2, then obtain the character from `j1` as `'A' + j1 - 1`. (Notice the different bases: `'a'` and `'A'`.)

You can implement that by changing the content of the inner loop like this:

```
for (j1 = 1; j1 <= i1; j1++) {
    if (j1 % 2 == 0) {
        ch = (char)('a' + j1 - 1);
    } else {
        ch = (char)('A' + j1 - 1);
    }
    System.out.print(" " + ch);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyPattern {


@SuppressWarnings("resource")

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Store the letters you desire in an array of strings
    String[] letters = {"A", "b", "C", "d", "E", "f", "G", "h", "I", "j" , "K" ,"l","M", "n", "O", "p", "Q" , "r", "S", "t", "U", "v" ,"W" ,"x" ,"Y" ,"z"}; 

    //create a Scanner object to take input from user
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many rows for Pattern 2?: ");
    int rows = scan.nextInt();

    if(rows > 26 || rows < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong input");  //as u know, number of alphabetics is 26

    //nested for-loop to print the required output
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          for(int j = 0; j < rows - i; j++) {
              System.out.print(letters[j] + " ");
          }

          System.out.println();
      }

         scan.close();
   }


}
```

This definitely solves your problem efficiently and cleanly.

Answer (score -1):

You only have to call `Character.toLowerCase(char)` method before printing. Replace your printing line with something like this:

```
System.out.print(" " + (j1 % 2 = 0 ? Character.toLowerCase(ch++) : ch++));
```